# Loading XML data without refresh

Tags: php, xml

I've script which get some values from XML record.

There's code:

```
<?php

//Data
$xml_data = '<image_process_call><image_url>https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/41/54/e44154308e3466d987665c6d50887f06.jpg</image_url><methods_list><method><name>collage</name><params>template_name=Nun Face in Hole;</params></method></methods_list><result_format>jpg</result_format><result_size>800</result_size><template_watermark>false</template_watermark></image_process_call>';

//Settings
$app_id = '';
$key = '';
$sign_data = hash_hmac('SHA1', $xml_data, $key);

//Send request
$request_url = 'http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/addtask?data='. $xml_data .'&sign_data='. $sign_data .'&app_id='. $app_id;
$request_xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$request_id = strval($request_xml -> request_id);

if (isset($request_id)) {
    $result_url = 'http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/getresult?request_id='. $request_id;
    sleep(6);
    $result_xml = simplexml_load_file($result_url);
    $result_status = strval($result_xml -> status);
    $result_img = strval($result_xml -> result_url);
    if (isset($result_img)) {
        echo $result_img;
    } else {
        echo 'Result image not found';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Request ID not found';
}

?>
```

The problem depends on time to generate the second XML file. $result_xml took few seconds so I have to use sleep(6) function.
If I remove this, I need to refresh the page (minimum three times) to get a link to generated image from second XML.

Do you have an idea how to do it more professionally? I can't be sure that every image will be generated in 6 seconds (sometimes shorter sometimes longer).
Is there any method for genereting the result only after receiving $result_img? Thanks in advance for your help!

I think it is worth writing.
In practice, it looks like this:
Script does $request_xml and XML from site return:

```
<image_process_response>
<request_id>2d8d4dec-4344-4df0-a1e1-0c8df304ad11</request_id>
<status>OK</status>
<description/>
<err_code>0</err_code>
</image_process_response>
```

Script gets request_id from this XML and do $result_xml. However, this is XML and script doesn't get image's url immediately. It needs to wait a few seconds.
After three times refreshing the page or using sleep(6) function finally we get:

```
<image_process_response>
<request_id>2d8d4dec-4344-4df0-a1e1-0c8df304ad11</request_id>
<status>OK</status>
<result_url>
http://worker-images.ws.pho.to/i1/9F1E2EAF-5B31-4407-8779-9A85F35862D3.jpg
</result_url>
<result_url_alt>
http://worker-images.ws.pho.to.s3.amazonaws.com/i1/9F1E2EAF-5B31-4407-8779-9A85F35862D3.jpg
</result_url_alt>
<limited_image_url>
http://worker-images.ws.pho.to/i1/3F797C83-2C2E-401C-B4AF-C4D36BBD442D.jpg
</limited_image_url>
<nowm_image_url>
http://worker-images.ws.pho.to/i1/9F1E2EAF-5B31-4407-8779-9A85F35862D3.jpg
</nowm_image_url>
<duration>2950.879097ms</duration>
<total_duration>2956.124067ms</total_duration>
</image_process_response>
```

**Edit:**

After trying to immediately generate the image I get such an XML:

```
<image_process_response>
<request_id>e615f0a1-ddee-4d81-94c4-a392f8f123e8</request_id>
<status>InProgress</status>
<description>The task is in progress, you need to wait for sometime.</description>
</image_process_response>
```

So this is reason why I see blank page...

**Do someone have an idea how to force a script to reconnect with the second XML until it finds a result_url?**

Comment: Adding a `sleep()` between setting a string literal and using that literal in a function call ___makes no sense at all___

Comment: Why do you use `$result_status = strval($result_xml -> status);` surely a simple `$result_status = $result_xml -> status;` is all you need there

Comment: @RiggsFolly Unfortunately, I still need to refresh three-four times page to get finally image.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used strval to put only string in array.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the manual and find out what that function does!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I guess simplexml_load_file should be replaced. How else can I get the xml value?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem depends on time to generate the second XML file.
>   $result_xml took few seconds so I have to use sleep(6) function. If I
>   remove this, I need to refresh the page (minimum three times) to get a
>   link to generated image from second XML.
>
> Do you have an idea how to do it more professionally? I can't be sure
>   that every image will be generated in 6 seconds (sometimes shorter
>   sometimes longer). Is there any method for genereting the result only
>   after receiving $result_img? Thanks in advance for your help!

According to [Pho.to API](http://developers.pho.to/documentation/sending-requests#request-format), An add task request is a queued POST request.

In my opinion, Send request in while-loop, but wait for smaller time instead of fixed 6 seconds, Check the `status` in `image_process_response`, Keep looping until it is not `InProgress`, After that, You can safely send second request to get processed image result.

You may encounter timeout issue due to low timeout configuration for [DoS protection](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html#dos) if you run this script on web server (via CGI/FastCGI), To resolve this situation, You need a queue for adding task in your HTTP request, and then process it offline (means without web environment).